# Autocorrelation Problem and adding independent variable

Tags: regression, autocorrelation, linear

Currently I'm working with time series data and my initial linear regression,:
My current model is

Yi = b0 + b1X1 + b2X2 + e

after I ran some assumption test there is autocorrelation on my model, and I did some research to avoid autocorellation.  One of the way is adding lag independent variable of Y, so my question is how to write my new linear regression model? and did I do the right treatment to avoid autocorrelation?

Yi = b0 + b1X1 + b2X2 + Y(i-1) + e

is this correct?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi : what you did was difference your model. So, you've now got the differenced $Y_t$ as the response in your revised model.  That technique is not designed to get rid of the autocorrelation but rather to attempt to make a non-stationary response stationary. So, you don't want to do that.

Instead, a lagged dependent variable is implemented by putting a coefficient on the response. So, the revised model would be:

$ Y_t = b_{0} + \rho Y_{(t-1)} + b_{1} X1_{(t-1)} + b_{2} X2_{(t-1)}+ \epsilon_t  $

( note that I assumed that the independent variables $X1$ and $X2$ have time
subscripts ).

Doing this may get rid of a lot of autocorrelation but, if $X1_{t}$ and $X2_{t}$ are highly correlated then you still may have a problem.

Note that technique above is a specific  kind of autoregressive distributed lag model (ARDL(1,1) if I have the notation correct) and any decent econometrics text will have a chapter on the topic.

Also, $\rho$ will have to be greater than $0$ and less than $1$ in order for the model to still be stationary (stable).